# Best key for a MySQL query on a large table (> 1M)

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I have query that is executing too long (more than 300sec). Can it be optimized with indexes or query modifying?
What is the best key?

```
SELECT
    `streams_channel`.`id`,
    `streams_channel`.`uid`,
    `streams_channel`.`provider_id`
FROM
    `streams_channel`
WHERE
`streams_channel`.`provider_id` = 1
         AND 
`streams_channel`.`followers` < 50
ORDER BY `streams_channel`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 15000 OFFSET 1440000;
```

Comment: How many rows would the query return without the index?

Comment: @GordonLinoff there are about 1,600,000 records, but this number can grow up to 3-4M i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best index for this query is probably `streams_channel(provider_id, followers, id)`.  You could also add `uid` so the index covers the query (that is, all the columns being used are in the index).

However, this index will not prevent the final sort for the `ORDER BY`, which may be the performance issue.  How many rows would the query return without the `LIMIT`?

It is possible that an index on `streams_channel(provider_id, id, followers, uid)` would prevent the sort.  You would need to test on your data.

Comment: I tried these variants: 1. streams_channel(provider_id, followers, id) 23 sec. Using index condition; Using MRR; Using filesort  2. streams_channel(provider_id, id, followers, uid) - 0.5 sec. - Using where; Using index 3. PRIMARY KEY 1 sec.

Comment: Looks like 2nd variant is the best one! thanks for it (these query times are taken from more fast server than I tested before, so final query times will be bigger)

Comment: And yes, streams_channel(provider_id, id, followers, uid) prevents the sorting. followers and uid are just covered by this index, "where" still preformed without index help.

Answer (score 0):

You need indexes on the columns in the WHERE clause.

You can see the effect of changes by running EXPLAIN before and after.  You should see TABLE SCAN removed by adding indexes.

Order of WHERE clauses matters. Make the first clause eliminate the majority of the rows and make it easier for subsequent clauses.

Answer (score 0):

`OFFSET 1440000` kills performance!  Even with the perfect index, the query must look at 1440000 + 15000 rows; that takes a lot of time.

But there is a way to optimize `LIMIT 15000 OFFSET 1440000` -- See [*Remember where you left off*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).

As I discuss in [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), the optimal index is

```
INDEX(provider_id, followers)
```

`provider_id` first because of "="; nothing after `followers` because it is tested as a 'range' (<).

Or (slightly better), you could provide a "covering" index:

```
INDEX(provider_id, followers, id, uid)
```

so that all the work is done in the index.  The two extra columns, `id` and `uid`, can be in either order, but must be after the other two.

What are you doing to do with 15K rows in the result?  Will that choke the client?